# Append an integer to a string name

Tags: javascript

Hi Im trying to iterate through a for loop from a long string of words held in a single string(wordlist), within impactjs:

```
var wordlist3 ="hellwhentrysthisbreaks"
var  xc=3;
var word_length = 4;
var words_in_round = 4;             
for ( i=0; i<words_in_round; i++){        
    var num_words = ['wordlist' + xc].length / word_length;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((num_words+1) - 0 ));
    n = Math.round(random / word_length) * word_length;
    random_word =(['wordlist' + xc].substring(n,(n+word_length)))
    random_words += random_word;
}
```

The above code works if i define wordlist as a global, but when i made it local num_words is not defined properly and random word throws this object has no method substring ..

My problem is, that since i converted to local variables when i append the string name and call .length it gives me the length of the new name (wordlist3.length = 9) instead of the length of wordlist3 =20 .. also i cant call the method substring on this object ...

Comment: You aren't explaining your problem very well. But I can tell you that `['wordlist3']` is an array which of course does not have a `substring` method.

Comment: Sorry! first time on stackflow, noob coder ..but you have highlighted the first problem: How do i append a var name and still maintain the strings properties

Answer (score 1):

```
['wordlist' + xc].substring
```

will NEVER work (well, unless it's preceded by another variable, eg. `foo['wordlist' +xc].substring`).  This is because, in Javascript `[anything]` means "an array of 'anything'", and (as Kendall mentioned) arrays do not have a substring method.

try:

```
random_word =(('wordlist' + xc).substring(n,(n+word_length)))
```

instead.

Comment: Changing the brackets got rid of the errors but not the result .. now wordlist3 num_words should = 422 but num_words (using brackets) = 3. So im getting wordlist3(9 characters) / 3 = 3 instead of the length of the wordlist3 string.